# Why NSString's doubleValue differ from the original string?

Tags: ios, nsstring, double

NSString is `@"16.240"`
it's doubleValue is `16.239999999999998`

What happened behind the scenes?

Comment: can you show ur code

Comment: the code is simple, just `self.price = text.doubleValue` in textDidChange method. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: if you are convert from double to string , it round the value

Comment: The ultimate, underlying issue is that the closest IEEE 754 64-bit binary float to 16.24 is 16.239999999999998436805981327779591083526611328125. The value you see depends on how many digits are preserved by the conversion to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Because of *floating point rounding errors*.

Long-story-short; not every number can be represented using floating point types.

References: [#1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors), [#2](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/rounding/), [#3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error).

Answer (score 0):

If it is value for price (or money in general) better to use `NSDecimalNumber` because it is save each part of float value as is.

```c
NSDecimalNumber *price = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"16.240"];
NSLog(price); //16.24
```

http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdecimalnumber